# Is it possible to create a CV in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, cv

It should [look like this](https://www.graphicpear.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/FF.jpg). What I have tried so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumns]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\large\scshape}{\thesection}{1em}{\\ \hfill}

\begin{document}
\section{Education}

\section{Something}

\end{document}
```

I will give it some more tries later on. Could be nice with some help.

Comment: Have a look on the documentclass [moderncv](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv?lang=en).

Comment: For example https://www.texdev.net/2011/11/05/writing-a-curriculum-vitae-in-latex-part-1/: it's certainly possible, some layout elements may be more tricky than others, ...

Comment: Yes, it can be done. The hardest part would be to find the icons fonts. I think `fontawesome` has a number of them.

Comment: http://lataix-sebastien.developpez.com/tutoriels/latex/tutoriel-moderncv/# There is a specific environment for it!